# How to control my fans

Tags: laptop, asus, fan, fancontrol

I am using Asus TUF FX505dy. How to control my fans? In windows I could use Armory Crate and set different power levels (silent, balanced and turbo). They also controlled my CPU frequency. There is a button combo (FN+F5) but it doesn't work in Linux Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I installed cpufreq with `sudo apt install indicator-cpufreq` and created a script that runs it. From there I can change the mode from Powersaving to Performance.

```
#!/bin/bash
indicator-cpufreq
```